# How to set a program to run on startup depending on the time of day when the computer is turned on?

Tags: windows, authentication, text-to-speech, startup

I want my computer to greet me whenever I turn it on. Simple enough, if you use this:

```
Dim speaks, speech
speaks=”Good morning, sir”
Set speech=CreateObject(“sapi.spvoice”)
speech.Speak speaks
```

But this works at all times of the day. For example, whenever I turn my PC on at 7 in the evening, it will say, "Good morning, sir".

Would it be possible to make a script which runs on startup, which greets me according to the time of day (for example, "Good afternoon, sir" after 12:00 PM)?

If not, would it be possible to run different script files on startup depending on the time? Like "goodmorning.vbs" for mornings, "goodafternoon.vbs" for afternoons and "goodevening.vbs" for evenings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. Just make a file with the extension .vbs and put it in your startup folder for your computer to greet you at startup. I also had to go to control panel, change text to speech settings to change my PC's default voice to female.

```
 Set Sapi = Wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
 dim str
 if hour(time) < 12 then
 Sapi.speak "Good Morning sir. All systems operational. Welcome back."
 else
 if hour(time) > 12 then
 if hour(time) > 16 then
 Sapi.speak "Good evening sir. All systems operational. Welcome back."
 else
 Sapi.speak "Good afternoon sir. All systems operational. Welcome back."
 end if
 end if
 end if
```

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/197719/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-make-your-computer-talk-to-you/

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim speaks, speech
DateInfo = Time
if Time() <= TimeValue("12:00am") then speaks="Good morning, sir" else speaks="Good afternoon, sir" 
Set speech=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
speech.Speak speaks
```

Comment: This tells you good afternoon at 1 in the morning. Can If else if nested statements be used here? (for example, if time is greater than 12 AM and less than or equal to 11:59 AM, speak good morning. Else if time is greater than or equal to 12 PM and less than or equal to 5:59 PM, speak good afternoon. Else speak good evening.)

Comment: Of course, you can, look in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9(v=vs.84).aspx